# Use receive_message_chain, with and another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using `rspec` to test a Ruby on Rails application. In my view I have this function to display a dropdown list. The application is running fine but I have problems trying to run the test. How can I use `receive_message_chain` and `with` and then again `receive`. How can I stub this chain?

**My View:**

```
<%= select_tag "filters[sponsorship_status]",
                  options_for_select(
                     Orphan.distinct.pluck(:sponsorship_status).map {
                        |ss| [Orphan.sponsorship_statuses.key(ss).humanize, ss] },
                    filters[:sponsorship_status]),
     {include_blank: "Any", class: "form-control"} %>
```

**My test:**

```
allow(Orphan).to 
          receive_message_chain(:distinct,:pluck)
              .with(:sponsorship_status)
                .receive(:map)
                   .and_return([["sponsorship_status1",
                      orphans_filters[:sponsorship_status].to_s]])
```

Comment: Listen to your tests. The need to stub so deeply is a signal that your code is not well-structured.

Answer (score 0):

I very much agree with the comment above that said you should listen to your tests and not try to mock this deeply. Also, it's typical to test views by checking the rendered output as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/view-specs/view-spec. What you've shown here is obviously not your actually test, but one of the mocks you've set up for your test.

That said, you've got several problems with your test code, most notably that you're trying to chain separate `receive` expectations, which you cannot do.

As an exercise, I created the code below to show one way that RSpec can be used to fully mock the particular code you have, although I've simplified the test by including the code under test within the example. In reality, you couldn't just stub `self` to stub the various methods. You've have to stub the actual methods being called within Rails.

```
module Orphan
end

describe 'code' do
  it 'does what it should' do
    filters_result = double
    options_result = double
    humanize_result = double
    key_result = double(humanize: humanize_result)
    pluck_result = double
    status_double = double
    allow(Orphan).to receive_message_chain(:sponsorship_statuses, :key).with(status_double).and_return(key_result)
    allow(Orphan).to receive_message_chain(:distinct, :pluck).with(:sponsorship_status).and_return(pluck_result)
    allow(pluck_result).to receive(:map) { |&block| [block[status_double]] }
    select_arg_1 = 'filters[sponsorship_status]'
    select_arg_3 = {include_blank: "Any", class: "form-control"}
    options_arg_1 = [[humanize_result, status_double]]
    allow(self).to receive_message_chain(:filters, :[]).with(:sponsorship_status).and_return(filters_result)
    allow(self).to receive(:options_for_select).with(options_arg_1, filters_result).and_return(options_result)
    expect(self).to receive(:select_tag).with(select_arg_1, options_result, select_arg_3)

    select_tag "filters[sponsorship_status]",
               options_for_select(
                   Orphan.distinct.pluck(:sponsorship_status).map {
                       |ss| [Orphan.sponsorship_statuses.key(ss).humanize, ss] },
                   filters[:sponsorship_status]),
               {include_blank: "Any", class: "form-control"}
  end
end
```